# Visualizar / descargar archivo PDF en página Web

Tags: php, web, nginx, apache2

Tengo una página web con ciertos archivos PDF pero no logro que se visualicen correctamente. En el navegador evidentemente funciona pero cuando hago click en el PDF aparece esto en una nueva pestaña:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He revisado el Apache2 y Nginx y al parecer está bien pero, ¿qué puede ser?

Comment: Muestranos el código de cómo estás intentando hacer, si usas una librería en específico también. saludos.

Comment: El de configuración de apache y nginx?

Comment: generas tu mismo los pdf o son archivos que ya tienes cargados en el sitio?.

Comment: Los archivos ya se encuentran en el sitio, pero curiósamente ahora me pasa también con las imágenes...

Comment: No se bien cómo está configurado pero has intentado ir directamente al apache sin pasar por el nginx a ver?

Answer (score 0):

Estás viendo el binario del archivo, porque el navegador entiende que tiene que interpretarlo como texto plano.

Para poder visualizarlo, tienes que agregar los headers correspondientes.

Un ejemplo:

```
<?php
$folder = './';
$file = 'myFile.pdf';
if(file_exists($folder.$file)) {
  //mime type
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  //filename indica el nombre del archivo, en caso de que se quiera bajar.
  //No necesita ser el mismo que el archivo original, puede ser diferente.
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$file.'"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ');

  echo file_get_contents($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: Voy a explorar lo que has comentado para ver si se trata de eso.

Comment: No logro hacerlo porque no se en qué fichero debo poner eso. Es complicado y complejo de explicar. Hay alguna forma de meterlo por javascript y/o por Apache2 o Nginx?

Comment: Te dejo dos artículos que te pueden ayudar:   
http://www.rephp.com/establezca-una-variable-de-entorno-en-htaccess-y-recuperela-en-php.html    
https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/variables-entorno-php-env.html